# Unpack a List in to Indices of another list in python

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

Is it possible to unpack a list of numbers in to list indices? For example I have a lists with in a list containing numbers like this:

```
a = [[25,26,1,2,23], [15,16,11,12,10]]
```

I need to place them in a pattern so i did something like this

```
newA = []

for lst in a:
    new_nums = [lst[4],lst[2],lst[3],lst[0],lst[1]]
    newA.append(new_nums)

print (newA) # prints -->[[23, 1, 2, 25, 26], [10, 11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

so instead of writing `new_nums = [lst[4],lst[2],lst[3],lst[0],lst[1]]` , i thought of defining a pattern as list called `pattern = [4,2,3,0,1]` and then unpack these in to those indices of `lst` to create new order of `lst`.

Is there a fine way to do this.

Comment: @sapensadler my goal is not to create a flat list, but to retain the lists structure as it is and alter the order of index by passing a custom list of numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a list of indices called `pattern`, you can use a *list comprehension* like so:

```
new_lst = [[lst[i] for i in pattern] for lst in a]
```

Answer (score 3):

`operator.itemgetter` provides a useful mapping function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [[25,26,1,2,23], [15,16,11,12,10]]
f = itemgetter(4,2,3,0,1)
print [f(x) for x in a]
```

> [(23, 1, 2, 25, 26), (10, 11, 12, 15, 16)]

Use `list(f(x))` if you want list-of-lists instead of list-of-tuples.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to using numpy, then try something like:

```
import numpy as np

pattern = [4, 2, 3, 0, 1]

newA = [list(np.array(lst)[pattern]) for lst in a]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In pure Python, you can use a list comprehension:

```
pattern = [4,2,3,0,1]

newA = []

for lst in a:
    new_nums = [lst[i] for i in pattern]
    newA.append(new_nums)
```

In numpy, you may use the fancy indexing feature:

```
>>> [np.array(lst)[pattern].tolist() for lst in a]
[[23, 1, 2, 25, 26], [10, 11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is slower than other, but it is another option. you can sort the list based on your pattern

```
a = [[25,26,1,2,23], [15,16,11,12,10]]
pattern = [4,2,3,0,1]
[sorted(line,key=lambda x:pattern.index(line.index(x))) for line in a]
[[23, 1, 2, 25, 26], [10, 11, 12, 15, 16]]
```